Count the number of commas within pyspark dataframe and exclude commas enclosed within double quote
I have below string present within pyspark dataframe column name text ( single column).
30,kUsUO,6,18,97,42,"SAM,K,KARAN",lmhYK,49,aLaTA,51,34,3,49,75,39,pdwvW,54,7,63,12,25,26,SJ12u,rUFUV,34,xXBv3,XHtz4,r4Fyh,14,20,0jZL2,izrsC,44,K5Kw3,8,tcKu7,5,RPLcy,kg4IR,Kvs3p,lyG09,dJmZB,34,84,7,qED2y,8uNen,5,96,81,88,bGgqK,FAsIV,81,YXZ,PQR,"Flat No B1002, Balaji Whitefield society, sus road, pune,Mh",22,591213,LbAo7,21,18,text,,,,,
I have requirement here to count the number of commas present in that column(text) but it should exclude commas which present within double quote
So regular expression should exclude commas present within below double quotes
"SAM,K,KARAN"
"Flat No B1002, Balaji Whitefield society, sus road, pune,Mh"
so correct count here is 68 ( excluding commas present within double quotes)
to achieve  this, I have used below code but this expression taking time. As I have 100 million records present within that dataframe, I am looking for better approach.
# Regular expression to count commas not within double quotes
df = df.withColumn(
    "CommaCount",
    F.size(F.split(F.col("SingleColumn"), r',(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)')) - 1
)

Any help appreciated

Pandas UDFs are meant to be faster for such cases.
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

@F.pandas_udf("long")
def count_commas(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return s.str.split(r',(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)', regex=True).str.len() - 1

df = spark.createDataFrame(
  data=[('30,kUsUO,6,18,97,42,"SAM,K,KARAN",lmhYK,49,aLaTA,51,34,3,49,75,39,pdwvW,54,7,63,12,25,26,SJ12u,rUFUV,34,xXBv3,XHtz4,r4Fyh,14,20,0jZL2,izrsC,44,K5Kw3,8,tcKu7,5,RPLcy,kg4IR,Kvs3p,lyG09,dJmZB,34,84,7,qED2y,8uNen,5,96,81,88,bGgqK,FAsIV,81,YXZ,PQR,"Flat No B1002, Balaji Whitefield society, sus road, pune,Mh",22,591213,LbAo7,21,18,text,,,,,',)],
  schema='SingleColumn: string'
)

df.withColumn('CommaCount', count_commas(df.SingleColumn)).show()

Not a pandas expert, but perhaps there is a more optimal way then the regex split.
